# Centering a \noalign section

Tags: math-mode, align, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to format a list of steps to solve a quadratic equation.  I have it so that it is aligning correctly for each of the math steps, but now I want to add some headings.
This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{aligned}  
x^2-4x+3&=&0\\\\  
\noalign{\noindent some text in the middle.}\\\\  
(x - 1)(x - 3)&=&0\\\\  
\noalign{\noindent Solve Factor 1}\\\\  
x - 1&=&0\\\\  
+1& &+1\\\\  
x&=&1\\\\  
\noalign{\noindent Solve Factor 2}\\\\  
x - 3&=&0\\\\  
+3& &+3\\\\  
x&=&3\\\\  
\end{aligned}
```

The problems that I still have are: the noalign steps are still showing a lot of space around them.  Also, is there a way to center the \noalign sections?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this would look a bit better?

```
\newcommand{\pheq}{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}}

\begin{align*}
x^2-4x+3&= 0\\
\noalign{\centering some text in the middle.}
(x - 1)(x - 3)&= 0\\
\noalign{\centering Solve Factor 1}
x - 1&=0\\
+1& \pheq +1\\  
x&= 1\\  
\noalign{\centering Solve Factor 2}
x - 3&=0\\
+3&\pheq +3\\  
x&= 3  
\end{align*}
```

I think you were overusing the `&`'s and the `\\`'s in your example. Note that the syntax for `aligned` (as well as `align`) is that of

```
x &= y
```

i.e. there is only one `&` right before the math relation. Since you also wanted to align, for example, the line `+1 +1` which does not have an `=` sign in the middle, I defined a `\pheq` which works just like a `=` with respect to spacing, but does not show up in the document.

Also note that a single pair `\\` is enough. If, for some reason, you want a bit more of space between the lines, use something like `\\[5pt]` instead of a double line break. Also note that there is no `\\` right before closing the environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!  The one issue I have remaining is that I would like to have the right side aligned to the right (like the left side is).  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

While I don’t think it is the most beautiful solution, replacing `\noalign{\noindent some text in the middle.}\\` by `\noalign{\centering some text in the middle.}` (note the missing `\\` at the end) solves the problem. I don’t know any simple way to improve the remaining spacing problems.